# Using ActiveCell.Offset with Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to move to the next line by offsetting from ActiveCell, but it either doesn't work or I get run time error.  Maybe this isn't possible within Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range), but sure would be nicer for users of this free workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("C4:C400")
 
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Set selectedCell = Application.ActiveCell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Select
        
    End If
    
    Dim cng As Range
    Set cng = Range("A4:A400")
    If Not Intersect(Target, cng) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Target.Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
   
End Sub
```

Comment: If the active cell is in columns A-D you can't go four columns to the left.

Comment: And do not use `ActiveCell` Use `Target`

Comment: Wow! That was silly of me not to see the correct number of columns, and embarrassed to admit that I just wouldn't have crawled out of the rabbit hole without your help.  THANK YOU!

Comment: As @ScottCraner said - `Target` is the reference to the cell that was changed, `ActiveCell` will reference the cell that the cursor moved to when you pressed Tab / Enter to exit the cell.  Also, put `Option Explicit` at the top of all modules - _Tools > Options > Require Variable Declaration_ to turn on by default.   You've not declared `selectedcell` and don't use it after it's first mention.

Comment: Thank you, Scott.  Works fine as shown below.  I have used this before, but got myself into trouble when I started using it on a calculated cell, which of course won't work, then moved a column and made a bad left turn.  Thanks very much to you and all at Stackoverflow for your time and efforts.                                                            
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("C4:C400")
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select